# How to extract a Gtk.Widget from Gtk.Builder in Python Gtk3+?

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm using Python 3 and Gtk 3.22.5 and am trying to change some existing menu code from `Gtk.UiManager` to `Gtk.Builder`. The code inserts a  menu bar into a box. Originally, this worked:

```
menubar =  uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")
box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
```

After migrating the menu definition to builder XML, I have this:

```
menubar =  builder.get_object("menubar")
box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
```

But there is a type mismatch:

```
box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
TypeError: argument child: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got gi.repository.Gio.Menu
```

**How do I extract a Gtk.Widget from the builder ?**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but it looks like your `menubar` object isn't a menu bar, but a menu model. A menu model is not a widget and can't be packed into a box.

You have to create the menu bar using [`gtk_menu_bar_new_from_model()`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuBar.html#gtk-menu-bar-new-from-model) and add it to your window.

Alternatively, if you put your menu model XML in a separate GtkBuilder file and put it in your GResource at the path `gtk/menus.ui`, the menu bar will automatically be created, as described in the documentation [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#automatic-resources).